# Select non-default attribute types in Rational Software Architect 8

Tags: uml, rational-rsa

Under UML Project, in a class diagram, when I try to select a type for an attribute, RSA 8 is providing an option to select primitive types of Java and UML only from "Select Element for Type" pop-up box. But, I want to select non-primitive types of Java as well as from other jars such as log4j.  How might I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the source containing the types (classes) you wish to use you could:

- Create a Java project containing those classes
- Create a new UML project (to contain the UML version of those classes)
- Apply the `modelLibrary` stereotype to the model (select the model, and click `Apply Stereotypes...` on the *Stereotypes* tab)
- Create a new transformation configuration (Java to UML), and transform the Java source into UML (with the Java package as the source, and UML model as the target)

Then back in your original UML model (the one where you want to add the types)

- Right-click on your UML model , and import the UML model project you just created as a model library (`Import Model Library...->Library in Workspace`)
- When you select a type for an attribute, you should now be able to search and use the types in the Java project!

When you transform your UML model to Java, it should generate with the correct types and import statements, so you'll just have to ensure those classes on the the build path.

Comment: If possible, please answer my other query - "Depict two dimensional array as a return type in RSA 8" @ [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931795/depict-two-dimensional-array-as-a-return-type-in-rsa-8].

Answer (score 0):

You can not manipulate jar classes with RSA 8.

I reversed jar files with EclipseUML Omondo : http://www.ejb3.org/jar_file_reverse/jar_file_reverse.html